# SonarQube issues are not getting listed when having multiple SonarQube instances

Tags: sonarqube

We are having two SonarQube instances running separately which have a common cluster IP. We use only one particular instance directly to run analysis.

In some cases the issues are not getting listed after analysis. When the "es" folder is removed and the server is restarted then the issues are getting listed. This is happening only when both the instances are up. When the other instance is down then the issues are listed properly after analysis.

Is there any issue with running multiple instance regarding elastic search module.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you connected two SonarQube servers to the same database. Such behavior is unsupported and you have to shutdown on of the servers.

See official statement on [SonarQube Community Forum](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/multiple-sonar-instances-one-database/3926/2?u=agabrys).